# ASP.NET/UserControls: How do I separate the "controller" from the "view"?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to separate the ascx ("view") and the ascx.cs ("controller") pars of a user control. Id like to move the controller part to App_Code to be resued while the view part is changed between projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, write the codebehind in some service class which extends UserControl, and in your .ascx file inherit that class

```
<%@ Control
Language           = "C#"
Inherits           = "Project.Business.Service.MyControl"
%>
```

Comment: How do I reference childcontrols of that control?

Comment: If in your .ascx file you have a control <asp:Label id="label" runat="server" />
In control code define protected Label myLabel, then set myLabel.Text = "x" for instance.

Answer (score 2):

In regular ASP.NET, even if you separate the code-behind and the ascx - they are still tightly coupled. It isn't a true "controller" (as separate from a view).

If you want this purity, consider ASP.NET MVC, which (obviously) addresses this in a different way.